# how to make nav brand centrally aligned

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code, what I'm trying to do is get the nav logo centered with equal pixels either side so the link on the left and right have the same distance between them.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")'></a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("PRODUCTS", "Products", "Products")</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#" style=" font-family: Foco-Regular">VISIT US: <b>f</b></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and this is my CSS

```
.navbar-brand {
background-image: url("/Content/Images/Brand-Background-New5.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: block;
height: 94px;
left: 42%;
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
top: 16%;
width: 301px;
z-index: 9999;
```

}

now on large screens i.e dessktops the above works fine, but when I minimize the browser, or someone opens the website on say a 15 inch laptop the navbar-brand is no longer centered it appears more to the right? how can I lock it so it stays centered regardless of the screen size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CSS calc() function: [css calc tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/)

What's happening is that on a small screen, 42% is the space to the left of the nav, the nav itself is taking up like 50% of the screen (since its so small) and you're left with 2% to the right.

What's the width of your nav? width: 301px;
What's the total width of a computer screen? 100%
So the space to the left of a perfectly centered nav should be: (100%-301px)/2
Solving the equation we get: 50%-150px

Just fix that one line in your CSS code to say:

```
left: calc(50% - 150px);
```

*THE SPACES AROUND THE - (minus) SIGN ARE IMPORTANT*

The resulting CSS should be:

```
.navbar-brand {
    background-image: url("/Content/Images/Brand-Background-New5.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: 94px;
    left: calc(50% - 150px);
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 16%;
    width: 301px;
    z-index: 9999;  }
```

Comment: I can't find the exact size of the nav within the bootstrap css, but as you can see from my code I have .container which has a width of 1170px and inside the container is where I have my logo and links

Comment: what EXACT ELEMENT are you trying to center? The nav? The container? something else? Add that css code to THAT ONE element you need to center. Right click on that element in chrome -> click "inspect element" and then click "computed" styles to see the exact width of it. Then, back in your code, make sure to change `width: 301px;` and calc `left: calc(50% - 150px);` to reflect the new width (for the calc function, the width should be divided by two.)

Comment: The brand, as mentioned in my question hence the css class .navbar-brand css which I provided.  But as I mentioned it's now working.